# Extract regression coefficient values

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have a regression model for some time series data investigating drug utilisation. The purpose is to fit a spline to a time series and work out 95% CI etc. The model goes as follows:

```
id <- ts(1:length(drug$Date))
a1 <- ts(drug$Rate)
a2 <- lag(a1-1)
tg <- ts.union(a1,id,a2)
mg <-lm (a1~a2+bs(id,df=df1),data=tg)
```

The summary output of `mg` is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = a1 ~ a2 + bs(id, df = df1), data = tg)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.31617 -0.11711 -0.02897  0.12330  0.40442 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        0.77443    0.09011   8.594 1.10e-11 ***
a2                 0.13270    0.13593   0.976  0.33329    
bs(id, df = df1)1 -0.16349    0.23431  -0.698  0.48832    
bs(id, df = df1)2  0.63013    0.19362   3.254  0.00196 ** 
bs(id, df = df1)3  0.33859    0.14399   2.351  0.02238 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I am using the `Pr(>|t|)` value of `a2` to test if the data under investigation are autocorrelated.

Is it possible to extract this value of `Pr(>|t|)` (in this model 0.33329) and store it in a scalar to perform a logical test?

Alternatively, can it be worked out using another method?

Comment: .@John - Why did you use `Pr(>|t|)` value of `a2` and not any one of the first three columns?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A `summary.lm` object stores these values in a `matrix` called `'coefficients'`. So the value you are after can be accessed with:

```
a2Pval <- summary(mg)$coefficients[2, 4]
```

Or, more generally/readably, `coef(summary(mg))["a2","Pr(>|t|)"]`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17824461/324364) for why this method is preferred.

Comment: How can we "discover" these properties of the `summary`? How did you find/know this?

Comment: You mean e.g. `coef(summary(mg))[, c("t value","Pr(>|t|)")]`? But thanks for the Link - I always forget that!

Comment: @javadba, you can ``str(mg)`` or ``names(mg)``, for instance.

Comment: @PatrickT thx. These little things are what make a big difference.  I found out about `data.table` and that _transformed_ my outlook on _R_ .. but still need these kinds of tips.

Answer (score 36):

The package `broom` comes in handy here (it uses the "tidy" format).

`tidy(mg)` will give a nicely formated data.frame with coefficients, t statistics etc. Works also for other models (e.g. plm, ...).

Example from `broom`'s github repo:

```
lmfit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
require(broom)    
tidy(lmfit)

      term estimate std.error statistic   p.value
1 (Intercept)   37.285   1.8776    19.858 8.242e-19
2          wt   -5.344   0.5591    -9.559 1.294e-10

is.data.frame(tidy(lmfit))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: To answer the OP from this: ``td[1, "estimate"]`` or ``td[td$term == "(Intercept)","estimate"]`` or even ``tdt <- as.data.table(td); setkey(tdt); tdt["(Intercept)","estimate"]``

Answer (score 9):

Just pass your regression model into the following function:

```
    plot_coeffs <- function(mlr_model) {
      coeffs <- coefficients(mlr_model)
      mp <- barplot(coeffs, col="#3F97D0", xaxt='n', main="Regression Coefficients")
      lablist <- names(coeffs)
      text(mp, par("usr")[3], labels = lablist, srt = 45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=0.6)
    }
```

Use as follows:

```
model <- lm(Petal.Width ~ ., data = iris)

plot_coeffs(model)
```

[image]

Comment: I've plundered your code and find it to be useful.  You may want to alter it so that it removes na values and it allows for the main title to be entered from the function.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, you can explore the contents of the model's output by saving the model as a variable and clicking on it in the environment window. You can then click around to see what it contains and what is stored where.

Another way is to type `yourmodelname$` and select the components of the model one by one to see what each contains. When you get to `yourmodelname$coefficients`, you will see all of beta-, p, and t- values you desire.