# Pipe `%>%` the results of a regression `lm`and return one of the attributes

Tags: r, regression, magrittr

I know can it's possible to return the `p-value` of a regression `lm` by doing this:

```
# regression model
  fit <- lm(y ~ x)

# two alternative ways to return the p-value
  glance(fit)$p.value 
  summary(fit)$coefficients[,4][2]
```

However, I need to pipe the result for the purposes of what I want to do. This is what I've tried without success:

```
lm(y ~ x) %>% glance(.)$p.value 

lm(y ~ x) %>% summary(.)$coefficients[,4][2]
```

#### reproducible example

```
library(magrittr)
library(broom)

x <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
y <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
```

Comment: `lm(y ~ x) %>% glance() %>% .$p.value `

Comment: Thank you @MartinSchmelzer ! This solution works with `glance{broom}` but it doesn't work with `summary`. Any idea ?

Comment: `lm(y ~ x) %>% summary %>% coefficients %>% .[,4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17824461/324364) that you avoid using the $ operator to extract coefficients. To be more explicit in what you're looking for, and more robust to library changes, try this instead:

```
coef(summary(fit))["x","Pr(>|t|)"]
```

But that makes your piping tough. You could try this, if it works for your purposes:

```
getp <- function(coefs) { return (coefs["x","Pr(>|t|)"]) }
lm(y ~ x) %>% summary %>% coef %>% getp
```

That works for me, and you could even add arguments for which column you'd like to extract in your one-line function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(magrittr)

{ y ~ x } %>% lm %>% summary %>% coef %>% .["x", "Pr(>|t|)"]
## [1] 0.18351
```

or

```
{ y ~ x } %>% lm %>% summary %>% coef %>% `[`("x", "Pr(>|t|)")
## [1] 0.18351
```

or use `2` and `4` in place of `"x"` and `"Pr(>|t|)"` in either of the above.