# Summary Extract Correlation Coefficient

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am using `lm()` on a large data set in `R`. Using `summary()` one can get lot of details about linear regression between these two parameters.

The part I am confused with is which one is the correct parameter in the `Coefficients:` section of summary, to use as correlation coefficient?

**Sample Data**

```
c1 <- c(1:10)
c2 <- c(10:19)
output <- summary(lm(c1 ~ c2))
```

**Summary**

```
Call:
lm(formula = c1 ~ c2)

Residuals:
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-2.280e-15 -8.925e-16 -2.144e-16  4.221e-16  4.051e-15 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -9.000e+00  2.902e-15 -3.101e+15   <2e-16 ***
c2           1.000e+00  1.963e-16  5.093e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.783e-15 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 2.594e+31 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**Is this the correlation coefficient I should use?**

```
output$coefficients[2,1]
1
```

Please suggest, thanks.

Comment: This is not correlation coefficient but parameter estimate.

Comment: @Miha - Which parameter to use then? Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577058/extract-regression-coefficient-values) was using specific parameter for extracting coefficient based on what was required by the OP.

Comment: So what is your desired output? Are you predicting the value of dependent value and you would like to extract the regression coeficient (estimates the change in the mean response per unit increase in dependent vriable)? If this is the case, than you already extracted this parameter by your code.

Comment: @Miha - Overall goal is to find the `correlation coefficient` between the two parameter in question. I am using `residual values` for `outlier` analysis, but just need to log `correlation coefficient` to see how parameters (stacked column wise) behave among each other.

Comment: Then you used the wrong code/test. To calculate corrleation coeficient between two parameters you should use: `cor.test(c1,c2,method="pearson")` which gives you correlation coefficient between two parametrs. In this case the results are the same (corrleation coefficient == to parameter estimates) but this is coincidence.

Comment: @Miha - Thanks. Are you sure that value won't match with what I am extracting with `output$coefficients[2,1]` for any unknown parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151112/discussion-between-miha-and-chetan-arvind-patil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full variance covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates is:

```
fm <- lm(c1 ~ c2)
vcov(fm)
```

and in particular `sqrt(diag(vcov(fm)))` equals `coef(summary(fm))[, 2]`

The corresponding correlation matrix is:

```
cov2cor(vcov(fm))
```

The correlation between the coefficient estimates is:

```
cov2cor(vcov(fm))[1, 2]
```