# Intercept and slope functions in R

Tags: r, excel, regression

is there an intercept and slope function in R like there is in excel? I know you can use the function "lm" to run a linear regression but for my purposes it would be much more practical to get the output simply as a number just like using intercept and slope in excel does.

Comment: Look at the `coef` function. If you pass it your `lm` object it will return the coefficients of your fit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract regression coefficient values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577058/extract-regression-coefficient-values)

Comment: `coef` is the way to do this in R. It is not so different to Excel; the SLOPE and INTERCEPT functions are doing linear regression to generate their values. It's best to learn "the R way" if you're using R and try not to compare with Excel.

Answer (score 6):

Once you've created your model, you can extract the intercept and slope values from the `coefficients` matrix within the model. This can be extracted either using the `coefficients()`/`coef()` function (these are aliases of the same function), or by extracting the coefficients directly using `$coefficient`. It's better to use the `coefficients()` function as this can also be used on models other than `lm`, and so it is a good habit.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 0.5*x + rnorm(100)

mod <- lm(y ~ x)
cf <- coef(mod)
```

`cf` will now contain a vector with the `(Intercept)` and `x` (a.k.a, the slope). You can then extract these using either numbers:

```
Intercept <- cf[1]
Slope <- cf[2]
```

or by their names:

```
Intercept <- cf["(Intercept)"]
Slope <- cf["x"]
```

If you're doing multivariable, then it would be advised to use the names, as the order of the output *may* be unexpected (and again, this is a good habit to get into)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question is asking for intercept and slope functions for the linear model with one independent variable and intercept:

**1) mean/cov/var** If the idea of the question is to *not* use `lm` then try these functions:

```
slope <- function(x, y) cov(x, y) / var(x)
intercept <- function(x, y) mean(y) - slope(x, y) * mean(x)
```

To test this use the built-in CO2 data:

```
coef(lm(uptake ~ conc, CO2))
## (Intercept)        conc 
## 19.50028981  0.01773059 


with(CO2, intercept(conc, uptake))
## [1] 19.50029

with(CO2, slope(conc, uptake))
## [1] 0.01773059
```

**2) lm** If it is ok to use `lm` then:

```
intercept <- function(x, y) coef(lm(y ~ x))[[1]]
slope <- function(x, y) coef(lm(y ~ x))[[2]]
```

**3) lm.fit** Another possibility is to use `lm.fit` like this:

```
intercept <- function(x, y) coef(lm.fit(cbind(1, x), y))[[1]]
slope <- function(x, y) coef(lm.fit(cbind(1, x), y))[[2]]
```